# JvisualVM: strange application behavior

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvisualvm, memory-profiling, heap-profiling

Here is my graphics from jvisualvm (after 2 hours, 20 hours, 22 hours of the application work). I can't explain such behavior. Please, help me with your advices.

I don't see memory leaks, but CPU usage is growing slowly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do not see any increase in CPU usage. CPU spikes are for GC activity.

Comment: However the behavior of GC activity has changed. After three more days the application hangs. And I can't understand the reason.

Comment: Yes, I believe that the CPU usage is growing due to GC behavior.